# Why my query string generates page not found for my view?

Tags: 7, commerce, views

In Drupal 7 I'm using a view export to download information for my orders.

If i go to the default url `/admin/commerce/orders` then the page downloads correctly.

However, I also have some filters so I can download only the orders I need, this passes a query string to the view which causes a 404 error (page not found).

In example:

> /admin/export/orders?status[0]=invoiced&event=All&school=&uid=&held=All&attach=admin_page

I can't find out why this is causing a 404 error.

I have another view with the same configuration and it works fine. It is a number of query or something?

Comment: What is your view's "no result behavior"? And are you using anything like [Views 404](https://www.drupal.org/project/views404)?

Comment: Could it be because `school` and `uid` are empty?

Comment: Cross check with passing individual parameter, I doubt the error is because of status[0], but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [views_data_export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export)? The most likely reason you are getting a 404 (are you sure it's not a 401?) is that your path starts with "/admin" and the menu system may be protecting it because its not sure which view you are loading.

Also, by default, Commerce rewrites all order and product SQL statements to enforce the permissions system. You can turn off the SQL rewriting if you know what you are doing (this is a security risk).

[image: disable sql writing]